# Excel Conditional Lookup with conditions available in different Rows & Cols

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am stuck in a weird situation where I need to perform a simple vlookup but the using different data points.

I have a mapper where I have a %Achievement of the employee @ Enter & State wise with their Slabs.

[image]

On second hand, I have a data sheet where I have the actual %Achievement of the Center state wise and I need to update the Slab from the above table. I have updated few of the entries FYR, however I have similar thing for almost 12000 entries of different combinations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excel 365, combination of FILTER & XLOOKUP should work.
Step 1: [Filter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) the row from slab sheet for the Centre/State which you need
Step 2: Use [xlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) with matchmode 1

Here is the rough code snippet in col F2 of actual sheet:

```
= XLOOKUP(E2, FILTER([slab sheet]!D2:N100, ([slab sheet]!B2:B100=B2)*([slab sheet]!C2:C100=C2), [slab sheet]!D1:N1, "#N/A", 1)
```

Comment: I am using excel 2013.